# VB.Net SQL DataAdapter Not updating on first run

Tags: vb.net, sqldataadapter

I am working with a SQL DataAdapter (sqlDa) and on the click of a checkbox event the sqlDa should run an update command.

The code is called, but the update event doesnt actually fire and I am unsure why.

I have stepped through and there are no errors, 
I have run SQL Profiler and it shows there is no SQL Event fired
Originally there was no Initializer so created one and the binding events are on the checkbox I am working with

So, I am a little stumped and need some help.

The code I am working with is

```
Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

End Sub

Private Sub boundCheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles boundCheckBox.CheckedChanged
    ControlSettingsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.ControlSettingsTableAdapter.Update(Me.BoundTestDataSet.controlSettings)
    Call diagnosticCheck(boundCheckBox.Checked) ' this is for diagnostic purposes only
End Sub

 Public Overloads Overridable Function Update(ByVal dataTable As boundTestDataSet.controlSettingsDataTable) As Integer
        Return Me.Adapter.Update(dataTable)
    End Function
```

In the initializer this is the control that I am working with

```
 'boundCheckBox
    '
    Me.boundCheckBox.AutoSize = True
    Me.boundCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Checked", Me.ControlSettingsBindingSource, "checkBoxSetting", True))
    Me.boundCheckBox.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.boundCheckBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 62)
    Me.boundCheckBox.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3)
    Me.boundCheckBox.Name = "boundCheckBox"
    Me.boundCheckBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(590, 40)
    Me.boundCheckBox.TabIndex = 0
    Me.boundCheckBox.Text = "CheckBox Bound To 'checkBoxSetting'"
    Me.boundCheckBox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
```

Any and all help much appreciated

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue

needed to add `ControlSettingsBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)`

```
Private Sub boundCheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles boundCheckBox.CheckedChanged
    ControlSettingsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    ControlSettingsBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
    Me.ControlSettingsTableAdapter.Update(Me.BoundTestDataSet.controlSettings)
    Call diagnosticCheck(boundCheckBox.Checked) ' this is for diagnostic purposes only
End Sub
```